# How do I Use a Scope Identity in a sql Server ad hoc query?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a primary key Admission_ID in a table,after the insertion I want to get the admission_Id from the table and assign into another variable ,and i want to do this using scope identity. I have attached the query also. Please look into it,any help would be highly appreciated.

```
"Insert into Admissions(Admission_date,Student_name,Father_name,Mother_name,DOB,Gender,Address,State, City,Pincode,Admission_for,Previous_school,Fees)values('"+txtAdmDate.Text+"','"+txtStudentName+"','"+txtFatherName+"','"+txtMotherName+"',"+dateTimePicker1.Value+",'"+ gender+"','"+ txtAddress+"','"+txtState+"','"+txtCity+"','"+txtPincode+"','"+cmbClass.Text+"','"+txtPreviousSchool+"','"+txtFees+"')";
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. First thing is you need to decide which DBMS you are using. mysql <> sql server. And before you write another line of code you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This code is wide open to sql injection and bobby tables loves this kind of thing. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO <> 
Declare @Admission_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO <next table>
```

Comment: I'd wrap that in a transaction in case of race conditions.

Comment: Not enough information about the DBMS to get too specific.  I was just providing the scope identity portion of the answer.  Point taken, though.